# JSON Remove trailing comma from last object

Tags: javascript, json, regex

This JSON data is being dynamically inserted into a template I'm working on. I'm trying to remove the trailing comma from the list of objects.

The CMS I'm working in uses Velocity, which I'm not too familiar with yet. So I was looking to write a snippet of JavaScript that detects that trailing comma on the last object (ITEM2) and removes it. Is there a REGEX I can use to detect any comma before that closing bracket?

```
[
    {
        "ITEM1":{
            "names":[
            "nameA"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "ITEM2":{
            "names":[
            "nameB",
            "nameC"
            ]
        }
    }, // need to remove this comma!
]
```

Comment: it's not legal JSON - whatever produced it needs fixing.  Not fixing that will just accrue technical debt for the next user of that output.

Comment: `,\s*\]` should do, but doesn't care about string literals.

Answer (score 42):

You need to find `,`, after which there is no any new attribute, object or array.
New attribute could start either with quotes (`"` or `'`) or with any word-character (`\w`).
New object could start only with character `{`.
New array could start only with character `[`.
New attribute, object or array could be placed after a bunch of space-like symbols (`\s`).

So, the regex will be like this:

```
const regex = /\,(?!\s*?[\{\[\"\'\w])/g;
```

Use it like this:

```
// javascript
const json = input.replace(regex, ''); // remove all trailing commas (`input` variable holds the erroneous JSON)
const data = JSON.parse(json); // build a new JSON object based on correct string
```

[Try the first regex](https://regex101.com/r/HW7DFe/1).

---

[Another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344328/json-remove-trailiing-comma-from-last-object/34347475#comment70449159_34347475) is to find every `,`, after which there is a closing bracket.
Closing brackets in this case are `}` and `]`.
Again, closing brackets might be placed after a bunch of space-like symbols (`\s`).

Hence the regexp:

```
const regex = /\,(?=\s*?[\}\]])/g;
```

Usage is the same.

[Try the second regex](https://regex101.com/r/HW7DFe/2).

Comment: This also replaces comma's inside strings, e.g. {"letters" : "a, b, c"}. The following just checks against trailing commas: fix.replace(/(.*?),\s*(\}|\])/g, "$1$2");

Comment: @bob That statement requires an \*. The code provided still removes a comma in string context given the following JSON `{ "chars": "1,2,3,},]" }`. The resulting output would be `{ "chars": "1,2,3}]" }`. This scenario is less common, so it's an improvement, but depending on the context this might or might not be an issue.

Comment: More generally, you will always have false positives in this case, because [a JSON can contain another JSON](https://tsplay.dev/mqoRYw)  (which can contain another JSON, and so on). That's why the issue must be dealt with on the generation stage: don't produce malformed JSON, and assume that if the input is a JSON, it is valid.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the Json input = [{"ITEM1":{"names":["nameA"]}},{"ITEM2":{"names":["nameB","nameC"]}},] without whitespaces.
I suggest a simple way using **substring**.

```
input = input.substring(0, input.length-2);
input = input + "]";
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, you can do a simple search/replace like this:

```
,\n]$
```

Replacement string:

```
\n]
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD9oU8/1)**

Code

```
var re = /,\n]$/; 
var str = '[  \n   {  \n      "ITEM1":{  \n         "names":[  \n            "nameA"\n         ]\n      }\n   },\n   {  \n      "ITEM2":{  \n         "names":[  \n            "nameB",\n            "nameC"\n         ]\n      }\n   },\n]';
var subst = '\n]'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 0):

I developped a simple but useful logic for this purpose - you can try this.

```
Integer Cnt = 5;
        String StrInput = "[";
        
        for(int i=1; i<Cnt; i++){
            StrInput +="   {"  
                     + "     \"ITEM"+i+"\":{ " 
                     + "      \"names\":["  
                              + "   \"nameA\""
                                + "]"
                  +"}";
                            
            if(i ==(Cnt-1)) { 
                StrInput += "}";            
            } else {
                StrInput += "},";
            }
        
        }
        StrInput +="]";
        
        System.out.println(StrInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove trailing commas in a complex json string using regular expression

```
  const regex = /,\s*([\]}])/g;
  const fixedJson = jsonString.replace(regex, "$1");
  const json = JSON.parse(fixedJson);
``
```

Answer (score 0):

The proposed regex approaches have a problem. If the JSON string you want to normalize is

```js
var jstring = '{"a":"5,}", "z":{"x":2,}, "b":4,}';
```

then applying `jstring.replace(regex, '')` will also remove the comma after `5` in the string `jstring.a` = `"5,}"`. This is not desirable.

Another approach, not resorting to regex, is:

```js
eval(`var result=${jstring}`)
JSON.stringify(result)
```