# Json parser to catch trailing commas in Java?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I was using the following to check if a json file was valid:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();   
parser.parse(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get((filePath.toString())))));
```

But the json file I am validating has trailing commas like below that it doesn't throw an exception for:

```
"file":"hello.htm"},]
```

Since this is the last attribute the comma isn't needed and is causing trouble in other areas of our application. Is there a parser or some way to catch this trailing comma?

Comment: Good option could be removing these commas before validation, look this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344328/json-remove-trailiing-comma-from-last-object

Comment: What `JsonParser` type is this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `JsonParser` is part of Gson, you're currently out of luck. Gson's parsing currently interprets the trailing comma in a JSON array as a `null` value. [It's wrong and a resolution seems to be planned for Gson 3](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/494).

In the meantime, you can use a different parsing library. I suggest Jackson. If you're just validating the JSON, you can use

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readTree(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath.toString())));
```

This will throw an exception, with a message similar to

```
Unexpected character (']' (code 93)): expected a value
```

indicating that it expected an actual value after the `,`, not the closing array symbol.

Answer (score 0):

When iterating the JSONArray, you could ask if the element is null:

```
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    if (!jsonArray.isNull(i)) {
        // parse here...
    }
}
```

And then you would be able to avoid the 'org.json.JSONException' exception.