# Groovy: validate JSON string

Tags: json, validation, groovy, jsonslurper

I need to check that a string is valid JSON in Groovy.  My first thought was just to send it through `new JsonSlurper().parseText(myString)` and, if there was no exception, assume it was correct.

However, I discovered that Groovy will happily accept trailing commas with `JsonSlurper`, but JSON [doesn't allow trailing commas](http://www.json.org/).  Is there a simple way to validate JSON in Groovy that adhere's to the official JSON spec?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977130/json-parser-to-catch-trailing-commas-in-java may be of use

Answer (score 13):

[`JsonSlurper`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.java) class uses [`JsonParser`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/JsonParser.java) interface implementations (with `JsonParserCharArray` being a default one). Those parsers check char by char what is the current character and what kind of token type it represents. If you take a look at [`JsonParserCharArray.decodeJsonObject()`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-json/src/main/java/groovy/json/internal/JsonParserCharArray.java#L139) method at line 139 you will see that if parser sees `}` character, it breaks the loop and finishes decoding JSON object and ignores anything that exists after `}`.

That's why if you put any unrecognizable character(s) in front of your JSON object, `JsonSlurper` will throw an exception. But if you end your JSON string with any incorrect characters after `}`, it will pass, because parser does not even take those characters into account.

#### Solution

You may consider using `JsonOutput.prettyPrint(String json)` method that is more restrict if it comes to JSON it tries to print (it uses `JsonLexer` to read JSON tokens in a streaming fashion). If you do:

```
def jsonString = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}...'

JsonOutput.prettyPrint(jsonString)
```

it will throw an exception like:

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 48, while reading '.', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
    at groovy.json.JsonLexer.nextToken(JsonLexer.java:83)
    at groovy.json.JsonLexer.hasNext(JsonLexer.java:233)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.java:501)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput$prettyPrint.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at app.JsonTest.main(JsonTest.groovy:13)
```

But if we pass a valid JSON document like:

```
def jsonString = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}'

JsonOutput.prettyPrint(jsonString)
```

it will pass successfully.

The good thing is that you don't need any additional dependency to validate your JSON.

#### UPDATE: solution for multiple different cases

I did some more investigation and run tests with 3 different solutions:

- `JsonOutput.prettyJson(String json)`
- `JsonSlurper.parseText(String json)`
- `ObjectMapper.readValue(String json, Class<> type)` (it requires adding `jackson-databind:2.9.3` dependency)

I have used following JSONs as an input:

```
def json1 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},]}'
def json2 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}],}'
def json3 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]},'
def json4 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}... abc'
def json5 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}'
```

Expected result is that first 4 JSONs fail validation and only 5th one is correct. To test it out I have created this Groovy script:

```
@Grab(group='com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module='jackson-databind', version='2.9.3')

import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature

def json1 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},]}'
def json2 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}],}'
def json3 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]},'
def json4 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}... abc'
def json5 = '{"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}'

def test1 = { String json ->
    try {
        JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json)
        return "VALID"
    } catch (ignored) {
        return "INVALID"
    }
}

def test2 = { String json ->
    try {
        new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
        return "VALID"
    } catch (ignored) {
        return "INVALID"
    }
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS, true)

def test3 = { String json ->
    try {
        mapper.readValue(json, Map)
        return "VALID"
    } catch (ignored) {
        return "INVALID"
    }
}

def jsons = [json1, json2, json3, json4, json5]
def tests = ['JsonOutput': test1, 'JsonSlurper': test2, 'ObjectMapper': test3]

def result = tests.collectEntries { name, test ->
    [(name): jsons.collect { json ->
        [json: json, status: test(json)]
    }]
}

result.each {
    println "${it.key}:"
    it.value.each {
        println " ${it.status}: ${it.json}"
    }
    println ""
}
```

And here is the result:

```
JsonOutput:
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},]}
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}],}
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]},
 INVALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}... abc
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}

JsonSlurper:
 INVALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},]}
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}],}
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]},
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}... abc
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}

ObjectMapper:
 INVALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},]}
 INVALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}],}
 INVALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]},
 INVALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}... abc
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}
```

As you can see the winner is Jackson's `ObjectMapper.readValue()` method. What's important - it works with `jackson-databind` >= `2.9.0`. In this version they introduced `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_TRAILING_TOKENS` which makes JSON parser working as expected. If we wont set this configuration feature to `true` as in the above script, ObjectMapper produces incorrect result:

```
ObjectMapper:
 INVALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},]}
 INVALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}],}
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]},
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}... abc
 VALID: {"name": "John", "data": [{"id": 1},{"id": 2}]}
```

I was surprised that Groovy's standard library fails in this test. Luckily it can be done with `jackson-databind:2.9.x` dependency. Hope it helps.

Comment: You save me big time. Thank you.

Comment: @Szymon thanks for the investigation, I was surprised that Groovy's json parser fails in many cases until I figured out why, I believe the dynamic nature of Groovy and the fast prototyping style requires some tolerances when parsing mis-formed schemas (json,xml...), I've found this is very useful when parsing different kind of HTML mixed JS for example, as well as working on REST api.

Comment: It always feels like an anti-pattern to rely on an exception to know if something is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

seems to be a bug or feature in groovy json parser

try another json parser

i'm using snakeyaml cause it supports json and yaml, but you can find other java-based json parser libraries over the internet

```
@Grab(group='org.yaml', module='snakeyaml', version='1.19')

def jsonString = '''{"a":1,"b":2}...'''

//no error in the next line
def json1 = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText( jsonString )
//the following line fails
def json2 = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().load( jsonString )
```

Answer (score 1):

can validate like this:

```
assert JsonOutput.toJson(new JsonSlurper().parseText(myString)).replaceAll("\\s", "") ==
            myString.replaceAll("\\s", "")
```

or a bit cleaner:

```
String.metaClass.isJson << { ->
    def normalize = { it.replaceAll("\\s", "") }

    try {
        normalize(delegate) == normalize(JsonOutput.toJson(new JsonSlurper().parseText(delegate)))
    } catch (e) {
        false
    }
}

assert '{"key":"value"}'.isJson()
assert !''.isJson()
```

Comment: Nice one! what would it be if it was a method `isValid()` in `JsonBuilder` ?