# How to trail extra commas to make json valid in php

Tags: php, mysql, json, regex

I have a json data which is saving in TEXT datatype in mysql but now I want to change datatype to json unfortunately json is not valid format. 
like extra , (commas) in unnecessary places
example (data and 0 are last elements of object/array):

Current

```
data,  }, },  }, {
data,  }, }, {
data,  }, ],  }, {
data,  }, ], {

0,  }, },  }, {
0,  }, }, {
0,  }, ],  }, {
0,  }, ], {

data",  }, },  }, {
data",  }, }, {
data",  }, ],  }, {
data",  }, ], {

data  }, },  }, {
data  }, }, {
data  }, ],  }, {
data  }, ], {
```

Should be

```
data  } }  }, {
data  } }, {
data  } ]  }, {
data  } ], {

0  } }  }, {
0  } }, {
0  } ]  }, {
0  } ], {

"data"  } }  }, {
"data"  } }, {
"data"  } ]  }, {
"data"  } ], {

data  } }  }, {
data  } }, {
data  } ]  }, {
data  } ], {
```

as we see above examples there are some extra commas i need to remove 
Is there any special code for move in php??? Help me

Update: 
For Valid JSON object: last item shouldn't end with comma
so Is there any way to loop through objects and if it last item in particular array/object remove comma if exists

Comment: See "JSON Lint". No silver bullet though. Unless you can describe the flaw as a rule I don't know how you would fix it programmatically. Is there conformity to the madness? Or is it just random text?

Comment: this json is for generate form by "jsonform", currently I am some completed forms in database, jsonform is not following standards so its working fine but where as json datatype in mysql is asking for valid json

Comment: The examples you gave are too vague. If you told me the "JSON" this from thing produces was flawed because it added an extra comma after every member's pair we could look to fix that programmatically probably with some simple string manipulation. Or, knowing the data, if you could extract the parts needed and reassemble that could work. If you can't explicitly say what is wrong I don't know how we can help.

Comment: @ficuscr sorry for that, but I just updated what is current and what should be

Comment: That helps. If looking to" remove trailing comma from last object" see this post and give it some upvote love if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344328/json-remove-trailiing-comma-from-last-object This regex worked well for me testing just now: `\,(?=\s*?[\}\]])` Looks like more though... Not sure about your missing quotes.

Comment: GIGO.  Cleanse the data before inserting.  If already inserted, then pull it out, cleanse it, and put it back in.