# Generating fully valid JSON with client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

So I am trying to create a JSON explorer / editor. I am able to parse the initial JSON into the div and format it how I like.

this is the function i use to loop through the initial JSON

```js
_iterate(_tab, raw_json){
    var tab = _tab;
    tab++;

    for(var key1 in raw_json){
        var data_type = typeof raw_json[key1];
        var d = String(raw_json[key1])
        if(d == String){
           d = "String";
        }
        if(d == Number){
            d= "Number"
        }
        if(data_type == "object" || data_type == "array"){
            this.input.append(`<json-tab tab-width="${tab}"></json-tab><div class="json-editor-input-container-2 -je-${data_type}">'<span class="-je-key">${key1}</span>' :{</div></br>`)
            this._iterate(tab, raw_json[key1])
        }else{
            this.input.append(`<div class="json-editor-row"><json-tab tab-width="${tab}"></json-tab><div class="json-editor-input-container-2">'<span class="-je-key">${key1}<span>' : '<div class="json-editor-input -je-${data_type}" contenteditable="true" for="{key: '${key1}', data: '${d}'}"></div>', </div></br></div>`)
        }
    }
    
    this.input.append(`<json-tab tab-width="${tab -1}"></json-tab>},</br>`)
}
```

in order to save the JSON I was going to retrieve the JSON from the text of the div using

```js
getJSON(){
    var json_text = this.input.text().slice(0, -1)
    return JSON.parse(`"${json_text}"`)
}
```

right now this is able to be parse by `JSON.parse();` but when i want to `console.log(getJSON()[0])` this returns `{`

am i not formating the JSON correctly. a live example of this can be found [here](http://104.236.0.12/)

Comment: Maybe first do a console.log(`"${json_text}"`) and run that through a JSON linter online...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BaseZen's answer was very helpful for me to understand what was going wrong with my code. My JSON was incorrectly formatted even though online linters say its correct. Along with what BaseZen pointed out, `JSON.parse()` will not work with trailing commas. To fix this:

```js
_remove_trailing_commas(json_string){
    var regex = /\,(?!\s*?[\{\[\"\'\w])/g;
    return json_string.replace(regex, '');
}
```

I found this information at SO post [JSON Remove trailiing comma from last object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344328/json-remove-trailiing-comma-from-last-object)

SO user Dima Parzhitsky's answer was what helped me also figure out this question.

Answer (score 2):

First, your `console.log` result doesn't make sense. A parsed JSON object is now usable in JavaScript and, if has (only) properties `x` and `y`, would result in `undefined` when requesting property `0` as you have. It looks like your call to `console.log` was to a different (earlier?) version of the `getJSON()` function, where it returned the raw string, and in that case it makes sense that you're just retrieving the first character of the JSON text: `"{"`.

But then, assuming the version of `getJSON()` as written, it would actually throw a parse exception:

```
VM1511:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
```

Looking at your site, I was able to do, in the console:

```
jsonString = $('json-editor').text()
// value: "{'partName' : '', 'partRevision' : '', ..."
```

That is illegal JSON. JSON specifies (only) the quotation mark `"` for strings (Unicode/ASCII 0x22) on page 7 of its [specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159).

The fact that `'partName'` is legal as a JavaScript string literal is irrelevant but perhaps confusing.

As a minor style point, simplify `` JSON.parse(`"${json_text}"`) `` to `JSON.parse(json_text)`.

Comment: I have made some updates to my site much more of it parses now except for a `}` I guess at the last position. what can I do to solve this. thanks for your quick response

Comment: The format of SO means encapsulated single questions. So you'd have to isolate, describe the issue in detail and post a separate question. Keep the example input as minimal as possible but that still fails.