# need to extract specific string with JQ

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

I have a JSON file (see below) and with JQ I need to extract the **resourceName** value for value = **mail@mail1.com**

So in my case, the result should be **name_1**

Any idea to do that ?
Because this does not work :

**jq '.connections[] | select(.emailAddresses.value | test("mail@mail1.com"; "i")) | .resourceName' file.json**

```
{
  "connections": [
    {
      "resourceName": "name_1",
      "etag": "123456789",
      "emailAddresses": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "123456"
            }
          },
          "value": "mail@mail1.com",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceName": "name_2",
      "etag": "987654321",
      "emailAddresses": [
        {
          "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
              "type": "CONTACT",
              "id": "654321"
            },
            "sourcePrimary": true
          },
          "value": "mail@mail2.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "totalPeople": 187,
  "totalItems": 187
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to store the parent object while selecting on the child array:

```sh
jq '.connections[] | . as $parent | .emailAddresses // empty | .[] | select(.value == "mail@mail1.com") | $parent.resourceName' file.json
```

Comment: works partially, I get this error : jq: error (at <stdin>:3211): Cannot iterate over null (null)
name_1
exit status 5

Comment: @TooNetCreation supposing some fields don't have the `emailAddresses` field, I've added `// empty` to deal with those cases

Comment: ok no problem. but I get an error with for instance : .connections[] | . as $parent | .emailAddresses | select(.value == "mail@mail1.com") | $parent.resourceName

Comment: @TooNetCreation try with `.connections[] | . as $parent | .emailAddresses // empty | .[] | select(.value == "mail@mail1.com") | $parent.resourceName`

Comment: I get this error : parse error: Expected another key-value pair at line 16, column 9
exit status 4

Comment: see here : https://jqplay.org/s/QuuOlqui4Q

Comment: @TooNetCreation you have one comma `"value": "mail@mail1.com",` before the closing `}``which makes jq fail to parse the json

Comment: yes I know, but this is how the JSON is formatted by Google APIs

Answer (score 1):

`emailAddresses` is an array. Use `any` if finding one element that matches will suffice.

```
.connections[] | select(any(.emailAddresses[];.value == "mail@mail1.com")).resourceName
```

Comment: same error : jq: error (at <stdin>:3211): Cannot iterate over null (null) name_1 exit status 5

Comment: see here : https://jqplay.org/s/pNN7rRoKr3

Comment: Then please update your example. The current one is working fine (apart from a comma typo in line 15): https://jqplay.org/s/Wr56ufX20b

Comment: As I said, remove the comma in line 15 after `"value": "mail@mail1.com"`

Comment: ok but this is how the JSON is formatted by Google APIs

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344328/json-remove-trailiing-comma-from-last-object/34347475

Comment: there is no way to do it with JQ? without using regex?

Comment: Maybe, but it would definitely go beyond the scope of this question. Open up a new one asking for how to convert a Google API response into proper JSON. Your question regarding the extraction of a specific value (given proper JSON), however, should be considered answered.