# Replace special charachters to fix JSON

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to fix someone else's JSON string so that I can parse it as a real JSON object.
The JSON has comma's after the last object of an array so it's not valid. I'm trying to remove it but I can't get the right formula. Any ideas?

Example string

```
"attributes":[]},]},
```

Should become

```
"attributes":[]}]},
```

I tried the following but all with no success.

```
string = string.replaceAll('},],', '}],');
string = string.replaceAll('\},\],', '\}\],');
string = string.replaceAll('\}\,\],', '\}\]\,');
```

Comment: What language are you using? Perhaps the original string is in JSON5 and could have other JSON5 artifacts niceties that aren't allowed in JSON. If so, I'd recommend looking into a library in your language for parsing and converting json5.

Comment: as @AdamWise said, JSON5 works great: https://jsfiddle.net/kv5918po/

Comment: The regex in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344328/json-remove-trailing-comma-from-last-object made it work. Thanks!